# Disable bootstrap component

Tags: theming

If I activate bootstrap theme, it overwrites the breadcrumb behavior of easy_breadcrumb with its own breadcrumb component. Is it possible to disable the component?

Answer (score 0):

It says here https://www.drupal.org/node/2885165 that "Bootstrap includes a custom breadcrumb module bundled with the theme. You'll need to disable them in your theme settings to use easy breadcrumb."

I also would like know exactly what "Disable Bootstrap custom breadcrumb module" exactly means or how to do that.